AWS EKS Cron seems not running completely
I have a flask app(a .py file) and there is a cronjob which run every 5 minutes.
A pod creates whenever a cron execute. In .py file I have added try, exception.
It seems to me .py file not running completely as per flow. And I am not able to trace/view error.
app_test.py
try:
    sql1 = "select * from table1"
    print(sql1)
    #fetch record 
    #print(first_result)
    #insert into another table

    sql2 = "select * from table2"
    print(sql2)
    #In logs its print/running till above only
    #print(second_result), It's not printing result, however records are there
    #Insert into table (not inserting data as its running till above)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception in Source Data Fetch", e)

Note: Data is large and its takes time to fetch full records
deployment.yaml
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: "Forbid"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 600
      template:
        metadata:
           labels:
             example.io/focalpoint.application.id: '19'
             app: test-eks-#env#-backend-app
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: test-eks-app
            image: tbs-docker.ap.example.net/example/test_eks_fls/test:#tag#
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
            args: ["python3 app_test.py"]
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/log
                name: access
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 500Mi
              limits:
                cpu: 600m
                memory: 3000Mi 
          serviceAccountName: test-#env#-service
          volumes:
            - name: access
              emptyDir: {}
          restartPolicy: OnFailure

I am using below command to view logs but not getting anything.
kubectl logs test-eks-cronjob-dv-285520-wffxn -n test-dev | tee C:\Users\amanshaw\Documents\test_dev.log

kubectl describe pod test-eks-cronjob-dv-285520-wffxn -n test-dev

